# How to fix error : Array to string conversion in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a radio button like this

```php
    <div class="card border-grey border-lighten-3 px-2 py-2 box-shadow-1 mt-1">
        <h4 class="content-header-title">Lesson</h4>
            @foreach($lesson as $key=>$less)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" name="lesson[]" value="{{$key}}"> <label>{{$less}}</label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
    </div>
```

I have function to save value from radio button, but when i click save it appears error like this

> Array to string conversion

Bellow is function to save

```php
    function saveLess(Request $req){
            $post = new Post;
            $post->title        = $req->title;
            $post->content      = $req->content;
            $post->file_video   = $req->video;
            $post->tags         = $req->tags;
            $post->lesson       = $req->input('lesson');
            $post->save(); 
        }
```

Comment: Why did you used the radio button name as lesson[] ?? is this having mutliple value?

Comment: lesson[] with input element returns array. Hence `array to string conversion error message`.             `$post->lesson       = json_encode($req->input('lesson'));` will suppress it though I dont recomment.

Comment: what's lesson in your database?

Comment: you are saving array to in $post->lesson . either save a string or json formated  lesson  eg   $post->lesson       =  implode(',',  $req->input('lesson'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the radio button name as `lesson[]` which refers as `array()` .
You have to set the name as `lession` .
Or if you want to pass multiple variables in radio button , Then use any of the following method .

`implode()` or `serialize` or`json_encode` .

If you want to pass only one variable ,
set ,

```
<input type="radio" name="lesson" value="{{$key}}">
```